# Suitescript 2.0 get saved search value by column index

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm using suitescript 2.0. I tried to get the value of that report using the below code. Which I referenced from the suitescript 2.0 [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSAPI/NSAPI.pdf)

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType restlet
 */

define(["N/record", "N/error", "N/search", "N/log", "N/format"], function(
  record,
  error,
  search,
  log,
  format
) {
  return {
    get: getProductionIncome
  };

function getProductionIncome(){


 var mySearch = search.load({
 id: 'customsearch_db_tot_rev'
 });
 var resultSet = mySearch.run();
 var firstResult = resultSet.getRange({
 start: 0,
 end: 10
 })[0];
 // get the value of the second column (zero-based index)
 var value = firstResult.getValue(resultSet.columns[1]); 


return "Amount: " + value;
}
});
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
error code: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT error message: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"Result.getValue: Missing a required argument: name","stack":["createError(N/error)","getProductionIncome(/SuiteScripts/revenue_sync_script.js:34)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"Result.getValue: Missing a required argument: name"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}
```

I have also tried the

```
var AccType= firstResult.getValue({ name: "type" });
```

but couldn't get the result because I don't know the exact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error code: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT error message:
>   {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"Result.getValue:
>   Missing a required argument:
>   name","stack":["createError(N/error)","getProductionIncome(/SuiteScripts/revenue_sync_script.js:34)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"Result.getValue:
>   Missing a required argument:
>   name"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

From the error message it seems your search does not contain 2 columns to fetch second column.

Please verify first if your search has 2 columns to being with.

> but couldn't get the result because I don't know the exact name.

To get column name, you can use `column.name` and `column.join` to get join.
For further reading check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4345767216.html) out.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Avi, it worked. Does the error SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT implies about not contain  2 columns? or is it from your experience?

Comment: `searchResult.getValue` accepts either _searchColumn_ or searchColumn _name_ so, if argument is not passed it throws **SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT** error. Since you were passing object it was evident that your search didn't had 2nd column.